# How to make an SSH RSA key auto accept?

Tags: ssh

I need to check a bunch of servers via SSH (RAM, disk, CPU model, etc).

I want to make a script for it. But the RSA key yes/no is getting in the way.

Is it possible to auto accept the RSA key while connecting to the server via SSH?

(I.e. ssh root@ip "yes" or some workaround?)

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@ip`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, this worked. I actually saw an example of ssh command like this, but a colleague told me that it is not possible...

Comment: How about the password? Is there an option to input it in the same command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell `ssh` not to worry about host keys, simply set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option to `no`, i.e.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@ip
```

If you also want to pass the password to it, you can do that using `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p your_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@ip
```

However, you'd be much better off using an ssh agent (such as PAgeant) and ssh key pairs - better than having your password hard-coded into a script somewhere.

Comment: I will not make a hardcoded password, i will make a script that takes ip and password as parameters ( ./script ip pass ).

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is not the same as auto-accepting the RSA fingerprint. This is wrong.